# Can we use "link" attribute for element finding?

Tags: c#, selenium

This may be a simple question for selenium users:

I know some of the attributes that we could use while finding an element like: Name, TagName, Css etc etc..

But can we use something like "link=-----" in c# for element finding based on that attribute??

[image: The image is the attribute which I get while I use Selenium IDE Recorder]

Comment: @user1177636: HTML like in the sense??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with Selenium IDE, here I assume `link=601-800 students` means something like `<a href='something'>601-800 students</a>`.

Then you can use `By.XPath` to locate the link with its text, or use `By.LinkText`, even `By.PartialLinkText`.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()='601-800 students']"));
//driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("601-800 students"));
```

**EDIT:**

If you have some links with the same text, try identify the unique ancestors.

E.g.

```
var headLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='header']//a[text()='601-800 students']"));
var mainLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']//a[text()='601-800 students']"));
```

If that's not possible, get them together by `FindElements` (note this is not `FindElement`), them index them.

```
IList<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[text()='601-800 students']"));
//IList<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("601-800 students"));
var firstLink = links[0];
var secondLink = links[1];
foreach(IWebElement link in links) {
    // stuff to do with link
}
```

Comment: Thanks..Its working..Also we can make use of "LinkText" here. But how can we differentiate if under same name multiple fields exist?

Comment: No, I don't think you can do that by `By.LinkText`. But it's possible for `By.XPath`, depends on the situation. Another way is you get the links with the same text, then index them by `someLinks[0]`, `someLinks[3]`, etc.

Comment: Thanks again for that. But if I index also, is it possible to select each one based on that index number?

Comment: Yes, use for or foreach loop to loop through. Answer updated once more.

Comment: So, what is the use of 
    
    var firstLink = links[0];
    var secondLink = links[1];

If I have 3 entries with that name, will "string text = link.Text;" selects the one which we need (may be 3rd entry or 2nd entry)?

Comment: `string text = link.Text;` was just an example I put there. It really depends on what you need there. Deal with the logic first, then Selenium, the last thing is C# syntax. Raise a new question explaining what you need.

Comment: Thanks again...Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565738/search-and-click-on-an-attribute-using-selenium

for my next question..